# How to make .local folder visible?

Tags: filemanager

So I'm trying to install mods for the video game known as [FTL](http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10959)

But when I open it, I can't find my actual directory. I looked and it said <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will unhide the folders. But it won't allow me to do that in the little directory thing built in to find my `data.dat`.

[image: File dialogue screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do is create a shortcut to my desktop. I'm an idiot.

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround for a handful of cases, but not a scalable solution. Imagine if you have hundreds of hidden files and folders. Would you want to create shortcuts for and clutter the desktop with all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> only works in file managers and dialogues that support them, e. g. Nautilus. Most applications are sensible enough to use the file dialogue offered by the user interface toolkit they're based on (in this case GTK+, which has supported this keyboard shortcut for ages). I don't know what archive manager you're using there, but you should consider switching to one with a better™ user interface, e. g. GNOME's and Ubuntu's default [File Roller](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/file-roller/).

Alternatively you should be able to enter the name of (hidden) files and folders in the “Selection” field and press “OK“ or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open or browse them in practically all file dialogues.